# To prove that a finite subset of N less an element is numerically equivalent to N(n-1)

Tags: analysis

my question is:

Let $a \in N\ $ where n ≥ 1. I must prove that $N_{n}$ - $\left \{ a \right \}$ is numerically equivalent (~) to $N_{n-1} $ .

I am aware of how obvious this fact is, but, I have to do a rigourous proof for it. I tried to use the obvious $N_{n}$ = n and thus $N_{n}$ less an element x must have a cardinality of n-1 and by definition,  $N_{n-1}$ has a cardinality of n-1, so, $N_{n}$ ~ $N_{n-1}$ but I was told this is not rigourous enough.

So, I know to show A ~ B you would have to show there is a bijective function from A -> B but I cannot think of how to present one in this instance, because we don't know where the element a is in $N_{n}$ as this is not given. Proving it is bijective is also a big problem here.

Thanks, all help is appreciated.

Comment: Hint, a piecewise-defined function on the intervals $[1,a-1]$ and $[a+1,\infty]$ should do it.

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused. The sets $N_{n}$ and $N_{n-1}$ are both finite, because they will stop at some value n, n-1 respectively in the natural numbers.

Comment: Could I say the following:
f(x) = x, x<a | x-1, x>a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, make a bijection between $n-\{a\}$ and $n-1$.  The obvious one of shifting all the elements from $a+1$ on down by $1$ works fine.  Now apply that bijection to all the elements of each subset of $N_n-\{a\}$ and you get a unique element of $N_{n-1}$  This is a bijection between the sets of subsets.

Comment: So, how would I specifically show that this is surjective?

Comment: Also, dealing with the injectivity, the first and second case when x, y <a and x,y > a are obvious. You can easily show that when f(x) = f(y) in those instances, then x = y. But for case three where x<a but y>a you get x = y-1 when f(x)=f(y) and I'm not sure how you deal with this when trying to prove injectivity.

Comment: For surjective, you just say, given $y$ in $n-1$, there is an $x$ such that $f(x)=y$.  If $y \lt a, x=y$.  If $y \ge a, x=y+1$.  The same logic (turned around) proves surjective the other way and you are done.

Comment: Thanks Ross, that's very helpful! I appreciate it. I think I have figured out all cases for injective too.